# How to get asp.net table column count programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am using asp.net table where I have to get the number of columns, I wonder there is no any property for asp.net table like grid has "Gridview.columns.count".
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is .count property for table class but it support over .net framework 3.0 and above see below snippet

```
//add table first
Table tbl = new Table();
int columnsToAdd = 4;
for (int x = 0; x < columnsToAdd; x++)
tbl.Columns.Add(new TableColumn());
//then get table count
int columns = tbl.Columns.Count;
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The following `Script` will help you to count the no.of rows or columns of a dynamicaly created table using the script.

```
<script runat=server>
Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender as Object, ByVal E as EventArgs)
    Dim MyRow as new HTMLTableRow
    Dim MyCell as new HTMLTableCell
    Dim i as Integer
    Dim j as Integer

    Table2.BGColor="Ivory"
    Table2.Border=2
    Table2.BorderColor="LawnGreen"
    Table2.CellPadding=4
    Table2.CellSpacing=3
    Table2.Align="Center"

    MyCell.InnerText = "Column 1"
    MyRow.Cells.Add(MyCell)
    MyCell = New HTMLTableCell
    MyCell.InnerText = "Column 2"
    MyRow.Cells.Add(MyCell)
    Table2.Rows.Add(MyRow)

    For i = 2 to 6
        MyRow = New HTMLTableRow
        For j = 1 to 2
            MyCell = New HTMLTableCell
            MyCell.InnerText = "Cell " & i & ", " & j
            MyRow.Cells.Add(MyCell)
        Next
        Table2.Rows.Add(MyRow)
    Next    

End Sub

Sub Anchor1_Click(Source As Object, E as EventArgs)
    Anchor1.InnerHtml = "Table 1: " & Table1.Rows.Count _
        & " rows - Table 2: " & Table2.Rows.Count & " rows"
End Sub
</SCRIPT>
```

The `Anchor1_Click` will full fill your requirement.

Thanks for listen to me